# Facebook Login Review with verification environment

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a question about the Facebook Login Review.
Can I submit the app in verification environment? (not production)

I understand my app must has Facebook Login Button and has feature with the permissions I wish to submit for review, but my app has already been published, without Login Button or any features with the permissions.
So, I want to submit the app in verification environment.

I couldn't find any description in reference for the above. so, I want answer.

Comment: Yes, I've done this. We pointed the FB app at the staging environment, then after review changed the settings to point to the production app once it was deployed. Facebook doesn't mind, as long as you're not doing something sleazy like pointing it at a totally different app after.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
But, what do you mean "point", exactly?
My facebook app has already been published, so if I change domain setting(production to staging environment), I think my app stop working.

Comment: I'm confused about how your app is using Facebook at all, then, if it currently doesn't have Facebook Login or anything else that requires permissions.

Comment: That said, consider a screencast (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/examples#instructions) in your review submission, and in the step-by-step instructions" fields put a big note "REVIEW IS FOR STAGING AT HTTPS://STAGING.EXAMPLE.COM/ AS THESE FEATURES ARE NOT IN PRODUCTION YET".

Comment: I understand. I'm grateful that you take care of me.
I have submit my app without any problem.